# js file not in jqueryMoblie

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, activerecord, href

I am jest parameters pass to the next page.Ever thing fine in browser but some code when check in my mobile it's not working so any one tell me what wrong in my code .I am confused .Code executed on browser but in mobile not working

```
$('#LEDList').append('<li " style="background-color: #DEDEDE;"><a href=" ../html/CustomerList.html?rono='+result.rows.item(i).firstname+'&roname=' +result.rows.item(i).lastname+ '" ></a></li>');
```

CustomerList.html showing but Customer.js file not working but When I call directly CustomerList.html in that time Customer.js will be fine

Please give me any idea about my problem

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile by default uses AJAX navigation. This means that CustomerList.html is not loaded in its entirety. Rathe the markup is loaded by AJAX and only the first DIV with data-role="page" is loaded into the current page.

So, if customer.js is referenced in the header it would be ignored. Either move the reference within the data-role="page" div so it too gets loaded, or disable AJAX navigation.

> http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/